# Is the Samsung Galaxy Core Prime S82OL capable of wifi tethering, if so, how?

Tags: wifi-tethering, samsung-galaxy-core-prime

I want to make a wifi hotspot because there is no internet access where I live. I rooted the phone using kingroot.

I started searching for a good app to use and figured I'd start with FoxFi which seemed to have a decent reputation. Got it installed, tryed to start it up and it tells me within 30 seconds to "turn on my mobile hotspot function" on my phone.

Since my particular model doesn't have that standard, after searching I came across a workaround by downloading a hotspot toggle widget. Tryed again, FoxFi seemed to be satisfied with that widget being used in place of an OEM toggle.

Attempted to connect to the new wifi hotspot using my pc and it would not identify the network, thus resulting in no internet connection. So I figured there was a problem with FoxFi and my phone and must've tried at least 10 other wifi hotspot apps both with root and without with good reviews. Still, to no avail has any one worked, most just crashed, another had the same issue as foxfi.

I'd greatly appreciate any help, I have been trying to figure this out for the last 10 hours and am at a loss. If it matters, it's a straight talk phone running off of a verizon network, but I do believe that is the only option for this particular model of the samsung galaxy core prime, being the S82OL version.

Comment: Ouch, a wall of text. Please consider an [edit] applying some formatting, inserting some line breaks at least at the proper places. That will dramatically increase chances anybody will even bother to read your question (not to speak of answers).

Comment: is your device 'career locked'? Because Wifi tether is available in almost 99% of android phones.http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_core_prime-6716.php

Comment: This might Help http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/86677/getting-confused-by-rooting-and-enabling-wifi-tethering?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

As @Avinash had commented, WiFi Tethering is available on all phones, including mine, which is also a Samsung Galaxy Core Prime (but has a different Model Number).

Were you able to at least connect to your hotspot, by your PC, even without a Network Connection (Internet Access)?
If so, then you would have to enable your "Mobile Data" or "Data Connection" to be able to connect to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me, a non-cellphone enthusiast, that Straight Talk (Walmart) requires a Hot Spot plan purchase in order to use my phone as a hot spot.

My phone is a Samsung Core Prime, version 4.4.4.

Thanks, Walmart.